# What does this mean for i from 1 to n in psuedocode?

Tags: algorithms, pseudocode

I am enrolled in the Algorithmic Toolbox course on Coursera, and as apart of the first week that are walking us through how to implement algorithms. But I am having trouble understanding the symbol and wording that they are using. This is an example of the psuedocode:

```
StressTest(N ,M):
while true:
n ← random integer between 2 and N
allocate array A[1...n]
for i from 1 to n:
A[i] ← random integer between 0 and M
print(A[1...n])
result1 ← MaxPairwiseProductNaive(A)
result2 ← MaxPairwiseProductFast(A)
if result1 = result2
:
print(“OK”)
else:
print(“Wrong answer:”, result1
, result2
)
return
```

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/For_loop, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudocode

Comment: This is pure English !